# Classification and measurement of feature basing on scan

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, classification, terrset

It`s not entirely a GIS question, however maybe somebody can help.

I need to automatically classify and then measure area of certain elements on image. That image is a scan of a thin wood slice and I need to classify vessels (so, in fact, holes in this slice).

Is it possible in `QGIS`, `ArcGIS` or `IDRISI Selva` to measure area of elements on scanned image while knowing the resolution of scan?

Example image: [image: wood slice example]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Kubson. Could you please provide a visual example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post. I need to classify all those "holes" and collect basic data about them (area, quantity)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  By asking the same question for three GIS products you are effectively asking three questions which I think makes this too broad.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to decide what GIS you are most likely to use and ask about just that.

Comment: It is done. I just wanted to know which product would be best suited for my problem.

Comment: Ist there a specific reason you are trying to accomplish this with ArcGIS? Generic image analysis toolboxes might be better suited for the segmentation / hole detection. Afterwards the size can be simply determined as the number of pixels in each patch multiplied by the size of each pixel (which you already know).

Comment: @AndreSilva I think this question is asking for a software recommendation rather than saying what has been planned/tried and where they are stuck. If you think differently then just vote to re-open. Interchanging OR vs AND will result in similar convoluted Q&As that I think we are trying to avoid.